# Zoom Out not working with static Button in Android

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to make zoom (By increasing the text size ,not scaling the view) buttons for text view. Here is my code snippet. 
( here first I get Text size of mytext_view and increment one when I click the button )

**For ZoomIn**

```
mzoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float x = mytext_view.getTextSize();
                mytext_view.setTextSize((float) (x + 1));
            }
        });
```

**For zoomOut**

```
mzooomOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float x = mytext_view.getTextSize();
                mytext_view.setTextSize((float) (x - 1));
            }
        });
```

I get zoomIn as expected, but when I click zoomOut Button it is also  **ZoomIn again**

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mzoomIn;
    private Button mzooomOut;
    private TextView mytext_view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mzoomIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btm_zoomIn);
        mzooomOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btm_zoomOut);
        mytext_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext_view);
        mzoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float x = mytext_view.getTextSize();
                mytext_view.setTextSize((float) (x + 1));
            }
        });

        mzooomOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float x = mytext_view.getTextSize();
                mytext_view.setTextSize((float) (x - 1));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kathi.stackoverflow.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mytext_view"
        android:text="Test! " />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btm_zoomIn"
        android:text="Zoom in"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btm_zoomOut"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btm_zoomOut"
        android:text="Zoom out"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my debug points when i click first of buttons

First zoomIn:
[image]

First zoomOut:
[image]

**Any unknown fact behind this, Help !**

Comment: show your button definitions like ..findViewById()... for two buttons and xml parts pls

Comment: @UğurB i edited  my Question with full code

Comment: Can you go into debug mode and see the actual value of `x-1`?

Comment: @JoelMin added debug values in Question

Comment: @JoelMin You can see unpredictable value when I ` getTextSize()` from same `mytext_view ` view object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect +1 -1 is not sufficient for this purpose. Proper way actually to increase or decrease by minimum sp value which is:

```
float onepx2sp = 1 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
mytext_view.setTextSize(x + onepx2sp);
```

or

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, x + 1f);
```

Comment: `textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, x + 1f);` works fine, but why +1 -1 not sufficient for this purpose ? **Any unknown fact behind this,** ?

Comment: getTextSize() returns scaled pixels and min sp value is based on your screen resolution and  bigger than 1px. when you dont tell setTextSize to set the value as a px it accepts it as sp value and 1px is smaller than your min sp value.

Answer (score 2):

**Ugur B**'s answer is correct. If you debug the `mtext_view.getTextSize()` value after calling `mtext_view.setTextSize(x + 1)`. You will notice that the actual value is much larger than the one you set it to. I logged the values like this:

```
            float x = mytext_view.getTextSize();
            Log.e("TEXT_OUT_OLD", String.valueOf(x));
            float new_val = x + 1;
            Log.e("TEXT_OUT_NEW", String.valueOf(new_val));
            mytext_view.setTextSize(new_val);
            Log.e("TEXT_OUT_AFTER", String.valueOf(mytext_view.getTextSize()));
```

The first time i pressed the **Zoom In** button. I go these logs:

```
04-17 09:45:47.063 22297-22297/com.test.myapplication E/TEXT_OUT_OLD: 21.0
04-17 09:45:47.063 22297-22297/com.test.myapplication E/TEXT_OUT_NEW: 22.0
04-17 09:45:47.063 22297-22297/com.test.myapplication E/TEXT_OUT_AFTER: 33.0
```

The `TEXT_OUT_AFTER` value each time increases much more than expected. Therefore, when you press the Zoom Out button, you actually just decremented the value by **1** but the new actual value is much more. Hence, the solution is to use Uger B's answer and Zoom In like this:

```
mytext_view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, x + 1f);
```

Zoom Out like this:

```
 mytext_view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, x - 1f);
```

**EDIT:**

The value you get is different, because of it's underlying implementation. If you see the source code of setTextSize. It's like this:

```
public void setTextSize(float size) {
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size);
}
```

Since, the new value is set based on `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP`. It doesn't directly set the value passed to the method, instead it first calculates the actual `SP` value based on screen density, then assigns the value.

Comment: if i set `mytext_view.setTextSize(10);` and get `mytext_view.getTextSize()` the value is different why ? any specific reason ?

Comment: `If you see the source code of setTextSize` Well said. Now its clear to me. :)